# Remote control an iPad to start app and activate Guided Access

Tags: ipad, guided-access

First I need to mention, that I'm not enrolled in the Apple Developer Program but willing to do so, if it would solve my use case.

We administrate several iPads in a museum. All iPads are hooked up in a stand and running the museum app (basically a website on a local server als Homescreen-App in Guided Access).

We are looking now for a way to restart the app and start the guided access without driving to the museum.
Is there a way to do this, without jailbreaking the iPads?

Answer (score 1):

The most appropriate way for you to do this would be to migrate your museum application from a locally hosted website into it's own application.

Doing this will then allow you to launch the iPads into Single Application mode, whereas in the current configuration you'd be able to set Single Application mode to safari, but not then restrict safari to only your local website.

Comment: I already have somthing familiar to the Single Application mode.
The Website was send to the homescreen, where i activated the guided access. 

The problem is, there is a some sort of bug in the web-application that makes the ipad unusable after a week.. We then need to restart the App by Hand

But we don't want to do that.. I am looking for a way to remotely or automaticly restart the museum Homescrreen-App at the end of the day

Comment: Single Application Mode is persistent across resets, and can also be activated remotely on new iPads as you add them - those are the main advantages over guided access, and why I recommended it. You can also use MDM to reset the iPad remotely when in this mode